# React functional component - accessing DOM elements directly vs via useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm building a drop down menu with React and GreenSock. It currently works just fine however I've been told I shouldn't select DOM elements directly. Instead I should use `useRef`.

Couple of questions: Is this statement true? and if so, if my code is working, is it necessary to change it?

Code [example on codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/rXBgNR)

Comment: Yes, it's true, you should not operate on DOM directly, but it would have been better if you have shown it in the code example as well

Comment: did you read this? https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @Ren codepen added to post